# How can I get largest prime factors between two numbers and store them in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, prime-factoring

I've been asked to solve this question:

> Write a function that takes two numbers `n1` and `n2` as input (with
>   `n2>n1`) and returns an array of largest prime factors corresponding to
>   each number between `n1` and `n2`.

My attempt is shown below, but my code is not working properly. It is not iterating from `n1` to `n2`. How can I get it right?

```
public static class A{
        static int testcase1=5;
        static int testcase2=10;

        public static void main(String args[]){
            A testInstance = new A();
            int[] result = testInstance.getLpfd(testcase1,testcase2);
            System.out.print("{");
            for (int i=0;i<result.length;i++){
                if (i>0)
                    System.out.print(",");
                System.out.print(result[i]);
            }
            System.out.println("}");
        }

        public int[] getLpfd(int n1,int n2){
            int current=0;
            int[] factors = new int[20];
            for(int j=n1;j<=n2;j++){
                for (int i = 2; i <= j; i++){
                    while(j % i == 0){
                        factors[current]=i;
                        j /= i;
                        current++;
                    }
                }
            }           
            return factors;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, first you're modifying your first for-loop variable (j) in the while-loop. That's not helping.

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest to separate the task of finding factors from the task of writing the largest factor. Here is a function to find factors:

```
function factors(n)
    f, fs := 2, []
    while f * f <= n
        while n % f == 0
            insert f at head of fs
            n := n / f
        f := f + 1
    if n > 1
        insert n at head of fs
    return fs
```

That returns the factors of *n* in descending order, so the largest factor is at the head of the list. Then it is easy to accumulate a list of the largest prime factors of a range:

```
function lpf(lo, hi)
    result := makeArray(0 .. hi-lo)
    for n from lo to hi
        result[n-lo] := head(factors(n))
    return result
```

I'll leave it to you to translate that to Java.

If your range is large, a variant of the Sieve of Eratosthenes will be very much faster than computing all those factors.